# DRF Invalid DateTimeField value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to set DateTimeField value via POST request in Django Rest Framework by receive current time instead of mine in `"active_date_from" and "active_date_to"` fields

I sent POST request with body

```
{
    "title": "myTitle",
    "tag": 7,
    "created_at": "2021-05-09 17:32:18",
    "active_date_from": "2020-01-01 00:00:11",
    "active_date_to": "2020-01-01 11:11:11"
}
```

But receive

```
{
    "result": {
        "id": 32,
        "title": "myTitle",
        "image": null,
        "description": "",
        "tag": 7,
        "tag_name": "124",
        "created_at": "2021-05-09 17:55:45",
        "active_date_from": "2021-05-09 17:55:45",
        "active_date_to": "2021-05-09 17:55:45"
    },
}
```

My code. In Model I am setting default value auto_now_add=True, but I expect that I can set these fields in the post method

```
#My configs

TIME_ZONE = "Europe/Moscow"

DATETIME_FORMAT = ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",)

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True
```

**models.py**

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=image_directory_path, blank=True, null=True
    )
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    tag = models.ForeignKey(
        NewsTag,
        related_name="product_tag",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active_date_from = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active_date_to = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DashboardNewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format=settings.DATETIME_FORMAT[0])
    active_date_from = serializers.DateTimeField(format=settings.DATETIME_FORMAT[0])
    active_date_to = serializers.DateTimeField(format=settings.DATETIME_FORMAT[0])
    tag = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=NewsTag.objects.all(), many=False)
    tag_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = (
            "id",
            "title",
            "image",
            "description",
            "tag",
            "tag_name",
            "created_at",
            "active_date_from",
            "active_date_to",
        )
```

**views.py**

```
class DashboardNewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedManager,)
    serializer_class = DashboardNewsSerializer
    queryset = News.objects.all()
    search_fields = ("title",)
    filter_backends = [
        drf_filters.SearchFilter,
        drf_filters.OrderingFilter,
    ]
    ordering_fields = "__all__"

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return DashboardNewsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        tag = self.request.GET.get("tag")
        if tag:
            return queryset.filter(tag__name__icontains=tag.lower())
        return queryset

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        response = {"result": serializer.data}
        return Response(
            response, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers
        )
```

Comment: You have to sett timezone

Comment: I have these configs (updated question)

Answer (score 2):

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. ***So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored***.

That is, in your case, Django just ignoring the given values for ***`auto_now_add`*** fields.

In the doc, there is also a section that describes how you can provide a "overridable value" at the time of object creation.